# Are QML var properties passed by reference or by copy?

Tags: qt, qml

I have two QML files as below:

```
//Page.qml
SelectionPage {
    model: localizationPageProxy.vehicleTypes //QObject* class exposed by property
    currentKey: localizationPageProxy.vehicleTypes.currentDataKey //QVariant property
}


//SelectionPage.qml
Item {
    property var model
    property var currentKey

    id: page

    ColumnLayout {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width * 0.9
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            clip: true
            model: page.model.data
            spacing: Number.EPSILON // I don't know why the data loading is faster with that
            delegate: Item {
                height: listView.height * 0.12
                width: listView.width

                RadioButtonItem {
                    height: parent.height * 0.85
                    width: parent.width
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: modelData.value
                    checked: modelData.key === page.currentKey
                    onClicked: page.currentKey = modelData.key //here the c++ property is changed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, is currentKey property of SelectionPage.qml passed by reference? 
If that was a copy I should not see the c++ model change. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Most are actually pointers under the hood…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than discussing copy vs reference, we should really be talking about bindings. When you do this:

```
currentKey: localizationPageProxy.vehicleTypes.currentDataKey
```

You're creating a binding. Whenever currentDataKey's value changes, currentKey will be updated too. But it is not a two-way binding. So changing currentKey does not update currentDataKey. Two-way bindings are pretty difficult to achieve, but there are posts on SO about them.

To actually solve what you're trying to achieve, I recommend adding a Q_INVOKABLE function to your QObject called `updateCurrentKey` or something. Then in your onClicked handler, do something like this:

```
onClicked: page.model.updateCurrentKey(modelData.key)
```

Comment: My question is: whit the code I posted I'm having a two way binding that I didn't expect. Why?

Comment: I suspect something else is happening, but I don't know what. If you make currentDataKey a read-only property, it should reveal whatever is actually trying to write to it.

Comment: Great hint, there was another item that was modifying the value. Thank you

Comment: Two way bindings are not _that_ difficult to achieve. I blogged about it on the KDAB.com website a while ago.

Comment: Thanks @André! I think I read that article. A lot of good stuff on KDAB’s site.